# Conventional folder/file names C#

Tags: c#, file, directory, naming

I wanted to know if there is a site that references "conventional" folder/file names. For example, one that explains what a "Models" folder should contain, what a "Helpers" folder should contain, etc.

I'm starting to develop projects with a lot of content, so it's important for me to start now to get the right habits to organize my work.

Thanks in advance for your help.

**EDIT:** To be more precise I would like to know the role of each folder/file according to their names because I see a lot of projects with Models, Helpers, etc folders and I don't really understand the difference between them.

My question is about console applications in .Net 6

Comment: Is this a Unity question...or?

Comment: @Llama I edited my question to try to be a little more specific, but no it's not necessarily related to Unity, but in general for console applications especially.

Comment: I don't think there is a huge amount of convention for this. So long as you can justify your choices and they make sense. Folders tend to map to namespaces, so whatever you'd put as a namespace.. some project types ar emote likely than other to have folders named a certain way - MVC projects likely to have Models/Views/Controllers and a Blazor app expects to have some like Pages

Comment: It would be easier to answer your question if you provided a full list of folders you wonder about and maybe a sample of a file inside it. StackOverflow is not designed for list style questions like "what are 10 good uses for an old sock?" And "what N different kinds of folder names might is find in a project and what are the purpose of the files inside them?" Is one of those kind of questions- hard to objectively deliver an answer that is "correct" when the specification is relatively unlimited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Models folder would probably contain classes like Person, Customer, Employee etc, most of the times models that are have their own data tables. A Helpers folder classes that maybe don't have a lot of logic, if that's the right word, for example an EnumeHelper class that return the description of an enum. If you want to see more about how to structure a project: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YiVqwoFMieg
In the description there are links to projects built with that structure, called clean architecture. I you're a beginner, maybe you want to see some beginner tutorials, see the structure there, try to understand it and gradually try to understand other architectures, like clean architecture.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for! :)